# I can't work with SQL values inserted by PHP

Tags: php, sql, powershell, phpmyadmin

i have inserted SQL values on tables with PHP that before has readed a .txt file.

The thing is that I can not work with those values.

PHP reads on the file .txt '8,00' and inserts this value correctly on the data base but if i do a strlen() this returns a 6 and it has tu return a 4.

TXT: [the text on .txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lrIq.png)

```
if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)){
    if ($fileError == 0){
        if ($fileSize > 5000){
            echo "Tu archivo es muy grande!";
        } else{
            $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
            $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
            move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
            $file = fopen("uploads/$fileNameNew","r");
            if ($file) {
                if (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
                    $ram = $line;
                }
                if (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
                    $cpu = $line;
                }
                if (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
                    $so = $line;
                }
                if (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
                    $gpu = $line;
                }
                if ($i=1) {
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO comparar (ram,cpu,gpu,so) VALUES ('$ram','$cpu','$gpu','$so')";
                    $conn->query($sql);
                }
                session_start();
                $session_array2 = array($ram,$cpu,$gpu,$so);
                $_SESSION['nombre2'] = $session_array2;
                fclose($file);
```

Comment: Marc are the SQL fields set up correctly?

What does the value echo if you retrieve it back from the database?

To me '8,00' is 6 characters and 8.00 is 4 characters if you read it as a string. Can you clarify this?

Comment: @kissumisha I can not retrieve any value inserted with PHP from the database. I mean, one of the strings that reads PHP from the txt file is 8.00 and it has obviously 4 characters, but before i put it on the database from PHP i do the strlen($ram) that is the one that has the 8.00 value and it shows me that his lenght is 6, so it is adding to the database a 8,00 with 6 lenght who 2 of them are "invisible".

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php: _"Reading ends when length - 1 bytes have been read, or a **newline (which is included in the return value)**, or [...]"_ - And `8,00` plus an `\r` and an `\n`, would make **six** characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification above. Seems that when you are extracting the text from the txt file you are also extracting the new line character \n.

Clean the value you want to insert with something like:

```
strlen(str_replace(array("\n", "\r\n", "\r"), '', $ram));
```

This should now return the correct length for the value are trying to work with.

Comment: It has to be like $ram2 = str_replace("\r\n","",$ram); for me, but u helped me a lot man, thank you so much <3.

Comment: If you're happy with the solution please accept the solution so it helps others in the future. Saludos!

Comment: But _please_ start to work with prepared statements, because the code is susceptible for SQL Injections